# Potential Energy and Black Holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, potential-energy, mass-energy, event-horizon

Let's say I have $N$ identical masses, $M$, that I happen to fit within their collective Schwarzschild radius $R_s = 2GNM/c^2$. Naturally, these masses are gravitationally attracted to one another and so there is some potential energy of the system.

What happens to this potential energy once the black hole forms? Is it converted into kinetic energy? Does it contribute the mass of the final black hole that forms?

Answer (score 1):

From Hawking's entropy formula $S=\frac{A}{4}$, we see that the initial entropy of the system is $S_{in}=NM^2$ (summing up entropies of individual BH). After all masses concentrate to form one final black hole, the maximum possible entropy will be $S_{max}=(NM)^2$. The actual Hawking entropy after collision of all smaller blackholes will be somewhat less than  $S_{max}$: $$NM^2<S_f<N^2M^2$$. Or $$\sqrt{N}M<M_{final}<NM$$ Here, the additional mass of $NM-M_{final}$ can contribute to (1) KE of BH, (2) angular momentum (3) dissipated in the form of gravitational waves.

The idea of a local gravitational potential energy is not well defined in GR and it only appears when we try to approximate relativistic kinetic energy of a test particle in Newtonian regime. Instead, we can say that our system of N blackholes had some initial configuration, and due to the 2nd law of thermodynamics these blackholes will finally combine to form a bigger blackhole of mass $M_f\leq NM$.

Comment: Dumb question: Does a black hole have gravitational potential energy? It seems no, but thats a big field to have no energy.

Comment: What about electromagnetic potential energy?

Comment: @AlBrown  Gravitational potential energy of a test particle that we use in Newtonian gravity is only a fraction of it's relativistic kinetic energy in Einstein's gravity. So, a particle experiences this potential energy due to it's free fall motion in curved space-time.

Comment: @MarcosMFlores For electromagnetic potential energy, we can consider charged BH whose metric is given by Reissner-Nordstrom solution. Here, area of event horizon A=$4\pi r^2_{+}$, $r_{+}=M+\sqrt{M^2-Q^2}$. The change in mass dM is contributed by : change in surface area A, momentum J and charge Q. $dM=\frac{\kappa}{8\pi}dA+\frac{Q}{r_{+}}dQ+\Omega_{H}dJ$ where $Q/r_{+}$ is the electric surface potential